# Analytic function from the unit disk to itself with specific values

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be analytic such that $f\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{2}{3}$ can $f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=-\frac{2}{3}$?
 Is there a theorem that prevents zeroes or bounds the derivatives

Comment: "analytic function with compact support" nope. if analytic function is $0$ on any nonempty open set, it is identically $0$. you can find this in any basic complex analysis book.

Comment: So that rules out trying to use something like a bump function? But an analytic function can have isolated zeroes in an open set right?

Comment: yes; yes\\\\\\\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Schwarz-Pick lemma $|\frac{f(\frac{1}{3})-f(\frac{1}{4})}{1-\bar{f(\frac{1}{3})}f(\frac{1}{4})}|\le |\frac{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}}{1-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}}|$

So we need $\frac{\frac{4}{3}}{\frac{13}{9}} \le \frac{1}{11}$ and that is incorrect, so no such $f$ exists